# Perform conditions in ThymeLeaf in Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot Thymeleaf and wanted to take conditional based decision. If condition matches, then whole row should be green else red

```
<body>
    <div class="container my-2">
     <h1>Active Workflow Details</h1>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div th:switch="${mdsAcives}" class="container my-5">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h2 th:case="null">No record found !!</h2>
                <div th:case="*">
                    <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mapping Name</th>
                                <th>Type of Mappings</th>
                                <th>Table Names</th>
                                <th>System 1 Count </th>
                                <th>System 2 Count </th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                         </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="m : ${mdsAcives}">
                                <td th:text="${m.mappingName}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${m.type}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${m.tableName}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${m.system1Cnt}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${m.system2Cnt}"></td>
                                <td th:style="${m.system1Cnt} eq ${m.system2Cnt} ? 'color: red;' : 'color: green;'}}" th:text="TRUE or FALSE"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<tr th:class="${your condition}? 'green' : 'red'">
```

I assume you have defined two CSS classes to make the row green or red.

Comment: Even this is not working ```<td th:style="${m.system1Cnt == m.system2Cnt ? 'color: red;' : 'color: green;'}}" th:text="${m.clCnt}"></td>```

Comment: Please read my example carefully. 1) its th:class that renders the class attribute. 2) the condition goes inside the ${}

Comment: Yes, Whats the issue in this? `<td th:class="${m.system1Cnt== m.system2Cnt} ? 'red' : 'green'}" th:text="${m.clCnt}"></td>`

Comment: How to compare two long values?

Comment: m.system1Cnt.equals(m.system2Cnt)

Comment: Its still not working, wondering why? and how to fix it?

Comment: Create a small reproducible example on GitHub and share the project